# Meteor: Search the nearest ride with two points

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, geojson

I am building a carsharing app and to set up rides, I have got this kind of insert in my db :

```
    {
        "_id": "YyPpkCDhTKStGw6CL",
        "authorId": "W6zvbcqit4Mw6a2iK",
        "stages": [
            {
                "caption": "Paris, France",
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    2.3522219000000177,
                    48.856614
                ]
            },
            {
                "caption": "Lyon, France",
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    4.835659,
                    45.764043
                ]
            },
            {
                "caption": "Toulouse, France",
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    1.4442090000000007,
                    43.604652
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
```

Stages are listed in the required order (Paris -> Lyon -> Toulouse).
Then I have a simple form with two inputs (**start** and **end**).
My question is: how can I find the nearest ride?

It seems I would have to do something like that :

Find rides where :

1. stages.X near **start**
2. stages.Y near **end**
3. X < Y

Do you have any idea how to make such a query?

Comment: you can use mongodb geospatial queries, 
you can start finding nearest points from X into stages.coordinates, 
if any ride found,
start comparing is it going through point Y or nearest

Comment: Your data is nicely formatted for GeoJSON so you have some research in here. Have you looked at the MongoDB geospatial indexes and queries? Do you realize that for meteor you can only do this sort of query on the server and return the results through methods or  a specifically published collection of results?

Comment: Have you then read enough to realize that "arrays" do not help you here as MongoDB can only return the "document" that is nearest to a query and not the specific array entry. Which I would like to point out to @Hiren as well. There is a way to get the nearest "array entry", but only one. So this all depends on what a "ride" means to you. Both start and end within possiblly the "same document" or within separate documents always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out an odd way to do the job, here it is:

```
// Set up of arguments and scope
var from =  [2.3522219000000177, 48.856614];
var to =    [4.835659, 45.764043];
var maxDistance = 2000; // in meters

// First, find ids where rides are near my "from" point
var ids = Rides.find({
    stages: {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: from,
            },
            $maxDistance: maxDistance,
        }
    }
}, {
    fields:{
        _id:1
    }
}).map(function(item){return item._id;});

// Then, find rows which are near my "to" point BUT restricting it to my ids found above
var results = Rides.find({
    _id: {$in: ids},
    stages: {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: to,
            },
            $maxDistance: maxDistance,
        }
    }
});

// Foreach the rows to filter the case where I match the points in the wrong order
var filtered = [];
results.forEach(function(row){
    var distFrom = [];
    var distTo = [];
    _(row.stages).each(function(stage){
        distFrom.push(calcDistance(stage.coordinates, from));
        distTo.push(calcDistance(stage.coordinates, to));
    });

    var nearestFrom = _.indexOf(distFrom, _.min(distFrom));
    var nearestTo = _.indexOf(distTo, _.min(distTo));

    if(nearestFrom < nearestTo)
        filtered.push(row);
});

// My final results!
console.log(filtered);
```

And the function to calculate distance between two points:

```
calcDistance = function(p1, p2){
    var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
    var dLat = rad(p2[0] - p1[0]);
    var dLong = rad(p2[1] - p1[1]);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(rad(p1[0])) * Math.cos(rad(p2[0])) *
        Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return Math.round(d); // returns the distance in meter
}
```